# Does $s(0) = s(1)$ define a vector subspace in $\mathbb C[X]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I believe that $s(0) = s(1)$ does not define a vector space in $\mathbb C[X]$, but I am unsure how to show it. I know it doesn't satisfy the zero vector condition, nor is it closed under vector addition or scalar multiplication, but how can I show this?

Is $\{s \in \mathbb{C}[X]:s(0)=s(1)\}$ a vector space?

Comment: Your question isn't clear! Can you explain your notation?

Comment: I want to show that s(0) = s(1) is not a vector space in all of complex numbers (the C should be that fat C)

Comment: You are correct. $s(0)=s(1)$ is an equation. Equations are not vector spaces.

Comment: What's $s(0),s(1)$ and what's $p$?

Comment: s(0) and s(1) are are arbitrary polynomials, and that p is supposed to be an s, apologies! I have changed it in the edit.

Comment: If $s(0)$ is a polynomial, then $s$ cannot be an element of $\mathbb C$. Please,edit your question so it will make sense.

Comment: I believe you are asking whether the set $\{ s \in \mathbb{C}[x] : s(0) = s(1) \}$ is a vector space. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes! That is what i mean! (I'm used to different notation)

Comment: What are you struggling with? Is the zero element in your space? How about the sum/a scalar multiple of polynomials in it? See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726880/is-s-a-subspace-of-v#comment1518061_726880) if you're still struggling.

Comment: So $s(0)$ isn't a polynomial but the value of the polynomial at the point $X=0$ right?

Comment: Well, if you know none of these conditions hold, surely you have a proof of this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $V = \{ s \in {\mathbb C}[X] \mid s(0) = s(1) \}$ *is* a vector space over ${\mathbb C}$. It is straightforward to verify this from the definition of vector space.

First of all, $V$ is not empty, as $0 \in V$.

Secondly, if $s, t \in V$, also $h := s + t \in V$: since $s(0) = s(1)$ and $t(0) = t(1)$, also $h(0) = s(0) + t(0) = s(1) + t(1) = h(1)$.

Finally, if $s \in V$ and $z \in {\mathbb C}$, then $zs \in V$, by a similar argument.

Comment: You forgot to verify that $V$ isn't empty.

Comment: @nik But that's obvious, as it clearly contains $2x^{10} - x^8 - x^7 + \frac{1}{2} x^4 - \frac{1}{3} x^2 - \frac{1}{6}x + \frac{7}{8}$.

Comment: It may be obvious, but it's still a necessary thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $\lambda : \mathbb C[X] \to \mathbb C$, $s \mapsto s(0)-s(1)$. This is a linear map, ie a linear functional (prove it). Its kernel, which is the set you're interested in, is thus a sub-vector space of $\mathbb C[X]$.